# Splitting numbers and letters in SQL Server 2005 table

Tags: sql, split

I have a column that contains values similar to:

```
034004         
034010         
06012AB        
06012C         
06012D         
06012P               
06026C         
06026P
```

Is there any way to separate or split these in two separate columns as numbers and letters? Does it matter that not all numbers contain letters?

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2005

Cheers in advance for anything that can point me in the right direct

Comment: Can the letters be intermixed (i.e. 12BA34CD) or will it always be number, followed by the letters (if any)? SQL's string functions aren't very great, but what you are asking can probably be done with them.

Comment: it is always a set format of a number followed by letters (if any)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming it is always one group of numbers then (possibly) one group of letters

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(YourCol, 0, P),
       SUBSTRING(YourCol, P, 8000)
FROM   YourTable
       CROSS APPLY(SELECT PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', YourCol + 'A')) Split(P)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great at splitting out the numbers and letters into 2 columns.  Much appreciated

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it worked for me.  However I don't understand what you did with the Split(P).  Can you explain it please?

Comment: @ristonj That just puts the result of the expression `PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', YourCol + 'A')` into a column aliased `P` that I can then reference in the `SELECT` clause instead of needing to repeat the longer expression.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the response, but then why did you use Split(P) as opposed to just P?